# Increasing & decreasing an array length to a input range value with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter, vuejs2

I'm building an client's range filter with **[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)**. I'm using a **`input`** tag with the type **`range`** which will filter the clients total **`length`**. I have been able to link the **`input`**'s value to the**`clients`** array , but it only works when decreasing the range, once I try to increase the `input`'s value it won't rerender the **`clients`**.

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <input @input="filteredClients" type="range" min="0" max="10" v-model="clientTotal" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(client, index) in clients" :key="index">{{ client }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        clientTotal: 10,
        clients: [
            'John Snow',
            'Cullen Bohannon',
            'Jamie Lannister',
            'Jane Doe',
            'Jamie Fraser',
            'John Dow',
            'Claire Fraser',
            'Frank Underwood',
            'Tony Stark',
            'Client Eastwood'
        ],
    },
    mounted() {
        this.filteredClients()
    },
    computed: {
        filteredClients() {
            this.clients.length = this.clientTotal
        }
    }
})
```

You can **[check this code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qfs8dzbv/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to approach this differently. By simply changing the length, you're actually removing elements from the clients array. Then when you increase the length again, you're just creating empty slots in the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Here's a suggestions: `filteredClients` now becomes a new, mapped array. No need to call it on an `input` event on the range input either; it's a computed property so it'll just update when any of its reactive dependencies (`clientTotal`) change.

```
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" v-model="clientTotal" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(client, index) in filteredClients" :key="index">{{ client }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    clientTotal: 10,
    clients: [
      'John Snow',
      'Cullen Bohannon',
      'Jamie Lannister',
      'Jane Doe',
      'Jamie Fraser',
      'John Dow',
      'Claire Fraser',
      'Frank Underwood',
      'Tony Stark',
      'Client Eastwood'
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredClients() {
      return this.clients.slice(0, this.clientTotal);
    }
  }
})
```

EDIT: `slice` is actually simpler and more appropriate than `map` for this case, as Neil.Work suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your computed you are shortening the array when you use `this.clients.length = this.clientTotal` so by the time you are increasing again, you already lost all your other clients in the list.

Your filter should instead `return this.clients.slice(0, this.clientTotoal);` and your list should use the new computed array.

That way you are returning a new array and not destroying the old one.